# How to get total number of documents in Marklogic optic api search?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9, marklogic-optic-api

how to count or estimate numbers of results when using marklogic optic api.

```
var results = op.fromView('x', 'y')
.where() <- I need to count all results from view after where.
.limit(200)
.result()
.toArray();
```

I would be nice to achieve something like this in response:

```
var count = cts.estimate(query); 
var items = fn.subsequence(search, 1, 20).toObject(); 
{ items: items; count: count }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to build on David Ennis' answer, as you're looking to get the total and the  results. These are two separate things you'll need to do, but it looks like this:

```js
let myView = 
  op.fromView('x', 'y')
    .where(conditions);

let total = fn.head(myView.groupBy(null, op.count('total')).result()).total;

let results = 
  myView
    .limit(200)
    .result()
    .toArray();
```

Comment: nice sample. Good catch on null over empty array - more elegant in JS.

Answer (score 3):

Note: the relationship between documents and results depends on how you created your TDE template. Some templates may actually create many rows from a single document. I am going to assume that your title related to documents should read "result" instead of documents since you reference "results" in the actual question.

For what you are trying to do, I would use [op.groupBy()](https://docs.marklogic.com/ModifyPlan.prototype.groupBy)

**Free standing example:**

```
const op = require('/MarkLogic/optic');
op.fromLiterals([
        {row:1, val:2}, 
        {row:1, val:4}, 
        {row:2, val:3}, 
        {row:2, val:5}, 
        {row:2, val:7} 
        ])
      .groupBy([],op.count('count', 'row')).result()
```

Result:  `{"count":5}`

The reason for the empty array in the `groupBy()` statement is to say group by everything (by not passing a column to group by)

Comment: It is annoying that we are missing the links to/from equivalent XQuery and JavaScript functions for some, and that the JavaScript `.groupBy()` is under `ModifyPlan` so can be harder to discover. I've updated with the correct link.

Comment: For me is ok to count many rows from one document because for my template this situation is almost impossible. I just need to count the result after filtering and before limit. I will try your solution, but I still need to return something like this: var count = cts.estimate(query);
var items = fn.subsequence(search, 1, 20).toObject();
{ items: items; count: count }

Comment: @MadsHansen Thanks for the link. However, the issue is even more confusing:  Try this:  http://docs.marklogic.com/10.0 -> choose Server-Side Javascript APIS -> in the search, type op.gr do not press enter and wait for the filtering to complete.. and.. no op.groupBy  .  SO, for a normal user using the API search, op.groupBy() simply does not exist without alot of digging.  It is strange to have to search for groupBy alone (although this works).

Comment: Yes, totally - there are RFE filed to update the docs and make this easier